# Using Hp Smartarray P400 with Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, server, hp, raid

I have recently been trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my ProLiant DL380 G5, which is using the RAID card Smartarray P400. When installing the desktop version, it wouldn't detect any hard drives, (whereas the latest Debian did but had DCHP problems) so I tried the RAID/Alternative Server version (which, after realising that this version is CLI only I don't want to use anymore). This, however, did not detect any storage either.

From what I have gathered, the P400 uses the ciss driver, which I believe has been replaced with hspa.

In the server version where it asks you to select a driver from the list after it fails to recognize storage, I attempted to use the hspa driver but this failed.

Any help on how to install Ubuntu (even if it's an old version) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the linux boot parameter:

```
hpsa_allow_any=1
```

Depending on whether or not this single parameter helps you or not, you ihgt have to add:

```
hpsa_simple_mode=1
```

as well.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* does the OP have to do? How? Do you have any additional Tips or ticks?Please **[edit]** your post to add information before the system deletes this because of low quality...  **:-(**