# Ubuntu server does not detect my disks in raid

Tags: boot, server, raid

When installing configure my ubuntu server, in the partition configuration part, it does not detect my disks in raid, it only detects the bootable USB.

Before I got to that point I had to put these commands in the console.

`losetup -d /dev/loop0`

`umount /cdrom -l`

I get stuck in the installation log process

I have a HP pavilon server DL380 g5, and the array controller is a P400

Comment: If the raid disks are not shown, there is no kernel driver included for the hardware.

Comment: and how can i do that?

Comment: How should I know your hardware ?

Comment: I have a HP pavilon server DL380 g5, and the array controller is a P400

Comment: Please always add the info to the question, as the comments might be deleted. Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030730/using-hp-smartarray-p400-with-ubuntu

Comment: I was already reading that article and it has not helped me with my problem